# SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN failed with error EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY

Tags: oauth, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The below code failed with error Token Validation finished.{"Validation Result":"Failed","Failure Reason":"EXTERNAL_OAUTH_JWS_CANT_RETRIEVE_PUBLIC_KEY"}

```
SELECT SYSTEM$VERIFY_EXTERNAL_OAUTH_TOKEN('ey...')
```

Security integration:

```
create or replace security integration external_oauth_azure
    type = external_oauth
    enabled = true
    external_oauth_type = azure
    external_oauth_issuer = 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxx/'
    external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx/discovery/v2.0/keys'
    external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://xxxx.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com')
    external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
    external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name'
    external_oauth_any_role_mode = 'ENABLE';
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen only if the external_oauth_jws_keys_url value is incorrect.
Are you sure the url used is correct? It should be the value copied from

1. Azure - App Registration -  - EndPoints - OpenID Connect metadata document url, paste this url in the browser.
2. From that detail,copy the url for `jwks_uri` and use it for creating the security object.

Please reverify if the value used is correct and compare it once again.